# Detect HDMI connection, plugin cable after startup / reinitialize xrandr?

Tags: hdmi, xrandr, kiosk

For my work I build some kiosk players but there is a small issue with them:

The players are distributed to other companies who sometimes startup the player first and then connect HDMI cable to the screen afterwards, in which case the player doesn't detect it (and sometimes the player reboots while the screen is off)

Is there a way to detect if HDMI is connected?
And if it is connected but not outputting/configured reinitialize xrandr? By using a hook on HDMI connect or something?

Note: on system startup it's automatically configured correctly by openbox, so there are currently no xrandr scripts.

System:

- Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic)
- Slim login manager (with autologin)
- Openbox
- Chromium running in kiosk mode (started through openbox autostart)

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is easier then expected just running an script every minute with `DISPLAY=:0 xrandr --auto` is enough to revive it :)